# Windows Modules Installer (TrustedInstaller.exe) not working on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, installation, iis

I'm trying enable some IIS7 features using the Windows Features tool (OptionalFeatures.exe), also known as

> Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on and off

After selecting features to install or uninstall I click OK, which brings up a "Please wait while your features are configured" dialog. I've let it run for up to three hours at a time, but the progress bar never moves from 0%. This doesn't seem to be directly related to IIS, since the same thing happens with any feature, big or small.

Looking at running processes in task manager, Windows Modules Installer (TrustedInstaller.exe) is running on high CPU and ever increasing memory usage, but nothing seems to happen. The same thing happens in the background when I try to install the IIS7 features using Microsoft Web Platform Installer instead of the Windows Features tool.

Other info:

- I'm on 32-bit Vista Home Premium SP1, running as Admin with UAC disabled.
- I've run sfc.exe /scannow, and didn't find any problems with system files.
- I've tried a clean boot by disabling all non-microsoft services.

Any ideas?

As an alternative solution, if anybody could tell me how to enable (classic) ASP support on IIS7 and/or get the IIS Management Console installed, that would also be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be some (rare) cases where installing features takes some hours.
You should let it work the whole day before giving up on it.

In any case, I suggest not to install IIS7 manually, but rather to use Microsoft Web Platform Installer .
This [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/06/02/microsoft-web-platform-installer.aspx) discusses how to use the Web Platform Installer.

Comment: I've already tried the WPI with same results. I'll let it run overnight and see if it helps. Interesting "feature", though.

Comment: Reboot before starting (just in case).

Comment: Well I'll be! The installation did indeed finish overnight.

Comment: All is well that ends well. In all such cases I know of, Windows Update went back to normal afterward, so don't be too afraid of the next time.

Comment: +1. I tried to install the Windows Vista telnet client. And I, too, had the same problem. I left the Windows Features tool alone for a couple of hours with the progress bar stuck at 0%. Finally, the tool finished its work and closed itself. Amazing!

Comment: @Fencliff: If the answer worked for you, you should upvote it by clicking the "up arrow" icon next to it.

Comment: @unforgettableid, no I *should* not. I could, and I did, but I don't think it's a requirement to upvote an accepted answer by any means.

Comment: @Fencliff: Thanks for the upvote. unforgettableid: Discussions of netiquette are best done on [Meta Superuser](http://meta.superuser.com/).